# how to remove the shortcut or function of a key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde, plasma

I don't know why a shortcut was added to a letter on My keyboard and now I can't use it.

Some solution I have already tried everything and I can not get it.

Comment: Are you in Kubuntu?  Please specify what OS and year.  For example Kubuntu 18.04. What shortcut is the key doing?  When you say you can use the key do you mean that when you type "a" something else happens?  Edit your question so we can all help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Kubuntu then go to System Settings.  Shortcuts.  Then the last one on the list and Custom.  Look for something in there.  If not then do a search for any shortcuts related to the key or what is happening.
[image]

Comment: I looked for it there but it is not there, some way to remove it by console?

Comment: PLEASE add details. What is the shortcut.  What is it doing. What version of Ubuntu/Kubuntu are you on?  Without these answers noone can help you.

Comment: kubuntu/ key "m" it has a shortcut that I can't remove it // in xev command it appears that

Comment: KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x4c9, subw 0x0, time 1776793, (70,76), root:(796,126),
    state 0x10, keycode 58 (keysym 0x6d, m), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6d) "m"
    XFilterEvent returns: False